# UIWebView sometimes do not fully load page / images

Tags: uiwebview, loading

I have the problem that sometimes in UIWebView a page is not fully loaded.
There is a picture gallery and if page is not fully loaded (means I don't get the delegate "ViewDidFinishLoading") some pictures are not loaded.
The picture gallery uses jquery.
As I mentioned it's not every time.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking to see if didFailLoadWithError: is getting called in this situation?
And if so, then find out why.

Comment: Yes, I set didFailLoadWithError and there is no error. I find out that somtimes not all images are loaded and therefore the viewdidfinishload is never called, because the missing images never get loaded. I wonder why it sometimes works and sometimes not and mostly it happens on the first request.

Comment: Sorry, I was away for some days...Here is a Link to an example website: http://mobil.ferienwohnungen.de/objekt/1676

Comment: Note: The problem occurs only in the uiwebview, not on a website.

Comment: I wasn't able to reproduce the problem. But I noticed once in the log that it seemed a frame within the page was taking a long time to load. Maybe have a look at the frame code and check its ok? Can't think of anything else as I tried it several times and was always ok.